# Delete option working as expected in postman, not working properly while triggering from Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have created a spring boot crud application, for resource I have created static list of objects.

i was able to perform all crud operations through postman working as expected.
When hitting through angular,i am able to delete only the object present in that static list.

I am not able to delete the object that is newly created through angular .

when i was checking in app logs i could see some difference in endpoint(found // slash)
actual(worked for static list's object deletion)-**DELETE "/users/Sa/todos/4**"
diff(not worked for new object created by me)-**DELETE "/users//todos/5"**
and the request not even entered the controller
**Angular code:**

todo-data.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../../Model/Todo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoDataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  retrieveAllTodos(name:string){


    return this.http.get<Todo[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos`);
  }

  deleteTodoById(id:number,name:string){
    return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos/${id}`);

  }
  retrieveTodo(id:number,name:string){


    return this.http.get<Todo>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos/${id}`);
  }

  updateTodo(id:number,name:string,todo:Todo){


    return this.http.put(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos/${id}`,todo);
  }

  createTodo(name:string,todo:Todo){



    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos`,todo);
  }

}
```

list-todos.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Todo } from '../Model/Todo';
import { TodoDataService } from '../service/data/todo-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-todos',
  templateUrl: './list-todos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-todos.component.css']
})
export class ListTodosComponent implements OnInit {

  todos: Todo[];
  deleteMessage:string;
  constructor(private todoService: TodoDataService,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshTodos();
    console.log('inside list todos-ngoninit');

  }
  refreshTodos(){
    this.todoService.retrieveAllTodos('Sathish').subscribe(
      response => {
        this.todos = response;
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }

    );
  }

  deleteTodo(id:number,name:string){
    console.log(`todo Id ${id}`);
    this.todoService.deleteTodoById(id,name).subscribe(
      response=>{
        this.deleteMessage=`Todo ${id} is deleted Successfully`;
        this.refreshTodos();
      }
    );

  }

  updateTodo(id:number,name:string){
this.router.navigate(['todos',id,name]);
  }
  createTodo(){
    this.router.navigate(['todos',-1,'Sathish']);
  }

}
```

todo-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Todo } from '../Model/Todo';
import { TodoDataService } from '../service/data/todo-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  todo: Todo = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    description: '',
    targetDate: new Date(),
    done: false

  };

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private todoService: TodoDataService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = +params.get('id');
      this.name = params.get('name');
    });

    if (this.id != -1) {
      this.todoService.retrieveTodo(this.id, this.name).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.todo = response;
        }
      )
    }

  }
  saveTodo() {
    if (this.id === -1) {
      this.todoService.createTodo(this.name,this.todo).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.router.navigate(['todos']);

        }
      );


    }
    else {
      this.todoService.updateTodo(this.id, this.name, this.todo).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.router.navigate(['todos']);

        }
      );


    }

  }

}
```

Spring boot code:

Controller:

```
 @RestController
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    
    public class TodoResource {
    
        @Autowired
        private TodoHardCodedService todoHardCodedService;
    
        @GetMapping("/users/{username}/todos")
        public List<Todo> retrieveAllTodos(@PathVariable String username) {
    
            return todoHardCodedService.getAllTodos();
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/users/{username}/todos/{id}")
        public Todo retrieveTodo(@PathVariable String username,@PathVariable long id) {
    
            return todoHardCodedService.findById(id);
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping("/users/{username}/todos/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> deletetodo(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable long id) {
            System.out.println("Entered delete controller");
            Todo todo = todoHardCodedService.deleteById(id);
            if (todo != null)
                return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    
        @PutMapping("/users/{username}/todos/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Todo> updateTodo(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable long id,@RequestBody Todo todo){
            Todo updatedTodo=todoHardCodedService.save(todo);
            return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(updatedTodo,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        @PostMapping("/users/{username}/todos")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> createTodo(@PathVariable String username,@RequestBody Todo todo){
            Todo createdTodo=todoHardCodedService.save(todo);
            URI uri=ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(createdTodo.getId()).toUri();
            return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
        }
    }
```

service:

```
@Service
public class TodoHardCodedService {
    private static List<Todo> todos=new ArrayList<>();
    private static  long counter=0;
    static {
        todos.add(new Todo(++counter,"Sathish","Learn Frontend",new Date(),true));
        todos.add(new Todo(++counter,"Sathi","Learn Fronte",new Date(),true));
        todos.add(new Todo(++counter,"Sat","Learn Front",new Date(),true));
        todos.add(new Todo(++counter,"Sa","Learn Fro",new Date(),false));
    }
    public  List<Todo> getAllTodos(){
        return  todos;
    }

    public Todo findById(long id){
        for (Todo todo:todos){
            if (todo.getId()==id){
                return todo;
            }
        }
        return  null;

    }
    public Todo deleteById(long id){
        Todo todo=findById((id));
        System.out.println("Inside delete by ID");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(todos.toArray()));
        System.out.println(todo);
        if(todo!=null){
           if(todos.remove(todo))
               return todo;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Todo save(Todo todo){
        if (todo.getId()==-1 | todo.getId()==0){
            todo.setId(++counter);
            todos.add(todo);
        }
        else {
            deleteById(todo.getId());
            todos.add(todo);
        }
        return todo;
    }

}
```

Logs:

```
2020-10-02 00:57:17.744 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/users/Sathish/todos", parameters={}
2020-10-02 00:57:17.744 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.todo.app.TodoApplication.controller.TodoResource#retrieveAllTodos(String)
2020-10-02 00:57:17.752 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-02 00:57:17.752 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [[Todo(id=1, name=Sathish, description=Learn Frontend, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDon (truncated)...]
2020-10-02 00:57:17.752 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-02 00:57:29.083 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DELETE "/users/Sa/todos/4", parameters={}
2020-10-02 00:57:29.083 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.todo.app.TodoApplication.controller.TodoResource#deletetodo(String, long)
Entered delete controller
Inside delete by ID
[Todo(id=1, name=Sathish, description=Learn Frontend, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDone=true), Todo(id=2, name=Sathi, description=Learn Fronte, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDone=true), Todo(id=3, name=Sat, description=Learn Front, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDone=true), Todo(id=4, name=Sa, description=Learn Fro, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDone=false), Todo(id=5, name=, description=Learn Frontend also ride, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:57:13 IST 2020, isDone=false)]
Todo(id=4, name=Sa, description=Learn Fro, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDone=false)
2020-10-02 00:57:29.091 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-02 00:57:29.091 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Nothing to write: null body
2020-10-02 00:57:29.091 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 204 NO_CONTENT
2020-10-02 00:57:29.099 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/users/Sathish/todos", parameters={}
2020-10-02 00:57:29.099 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.todo.app.TodoApplication.controller.TodoResource#retrieveAllTodos(String)
2020-10-02 00:57:29.099 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-02 00:57:29.099 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [[Todo(id=1, name=Sathish, description=Learn Frontend, targetDate=Fri Oct 02 00:49:40 IST 2020, isDon (truncated)...]
2020-10-02 00:57:29.099 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-02 00:57:36.191 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DELETE "/users//todos/5", parameters={}
2020-10-02 00:57:36.191 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-02 00:57:36.199 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-10-02 00:57:36.199 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-10-02 00:57:36.207 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for DELETE "/error", parameters={}
2020-10-02 00:57:36.207 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2020-10-02 00:57:36.215 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2020-10-02 00:57:36.215 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Fri Oct 02 00:57:36 IST 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
2020-10-02 00:57:36.231 DEBUG 22328 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: Can you show the payload that you are sending?

Comment: Can you check to see if it's just the `/` at the end of `@PostMapping("/users/{username}/todos/")`. Maybe remove that `/` at the end in the controller or append it to your request in your UI to make sure the URIs match exactly.

Comment: @OTheriault Thanks for correcting me. this is the actual issue.its resolved after correcting it

Answer (score 0):

### Error code 405

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Means that you should check the data that you are sending. Best way would be to debug it or `console.log()`it before the post request.

Example:

```
 createTodo(name:string,todo:Todo){
    console.log(todo);
    debugger;
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/users/${name}/todos`,todo);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining WebConfig in your springboot application and add all the http allowed methods

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time.

I made a small logical error in angular code,
on creating a post request, i was setting id=-1 and name is left blank.

As i am using the name field for creating a request url DELETE "/users/{username}/todos/4
its gone blank /users//todos/4
and not able to match the url at backend.

getting that error.

i feel very happy, that we have pepole to correct us , when we are wrong